# Call ASP.NET 2.0 Server side code from Javascript

Tags: asp.net

I'm struggling with this for the past 3 days. I need to call asp.net serverside code from Javascript when the user closes the browser. I'm using the following code to accomplish this. In my asp.net form I have various validation controls. Even if there are some validation errors, When I close the form the server side code works perfectly in my development box(windows 7). But the same code doesnt work in my production environment(windows server).

Does it have something to do with the Validation summary or Validation controls. The button control has Causes validation set to false. So even if there is a validation error still my form will post back. Am I correct? I suspect the form is not getting post back to the server when there is a validation error. But i'm disabling all the validation controls in the javascript before calling the button click event. Can someone throw some light on this issue.

There are few blogs which suggests to use JQUERY, AJAX (Pagemethods and script manager).

```
        function ConfirmClose(e) {

        var evtobj = window.event ? event : e;
        if (evtobj == e) {
            //firefox
            if (!evtobj.clientY) {
                evtobj.returnValue = message;
            }
        }
        else {
            //IE
            if (evtobj.clientY < 0) {
                DisablePageValidators();
                document.getElementById('<%# buttonBrowserCloseClick.ClientID %>').click();
            }
        }
    }

function DisablePageValidators() {
        if ((typeof (Page_Validators) != "undefined") && (Page_Validators != null)) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                ValidatorEnable(Page_Validators[i], false);
            }
        }
    }


//HTML 
<div style="display:none" >
    <asp:Button ID="buttonBrowserCloseClick" runat="server" 
        onclick="buttonBrowserCloseClick_Click" Text="Button" 
        Width="141px" CausesValidation="False"  />


//Server Code
protected void buttonBrowserCloseClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Some C# code goes here
 }
```

Comment: You can't really trap browser closing events in any standards compliant way.

Comment: You need to use AJAX. Basically, you're attempting to make a client-side call to a server side method asynchronously. In other words, it needs to be asynchronous, because after the user closes the browser - you cant magically 'halt' the operation and wait for your server side code to complete. You need to hook into the client-side browser closing event, then fire off some AJAX to accomplish what you want.

Comment: RPM1984 - Does it mean my application should be AJAX enabled or Do I need to use XMLHttpRequest.. can you add provide some links

Answer (score 0):

Look at following links:

They describe how you can react on browser closing in JavaScript. With this you can initialize an ajax request from JavaScript to the server (with help of jQuery or any other JavaScript framework)!

https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm (works in Firefox and IE)

Hope this helps!